# LRT signficiant but not planned contrasts (mixed model)

Tags: generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, likelihood-ratio, contrasts

I set up multiple models (each model adding a main effect and an interaction) with `glmer`from the R package `lme4`.
Conducting a Likelihood ratio test, I compared the models. The LRT showed two main effects:

```
anova(baselinemodel5, stimM5, carryM5, operationM5, stim_carry5, operation_carry5, stim_operation5, trainingM5)

[...]
                 npar    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance   Chisq Df Pr(>Chisq)    
baselinemodel5      3 3318.4 3337.7 -1656.2   3312.4                          
stimM5              4 3320.4 3346.0 -1656.2   3312.4  0.0470  1  0.8283920    
carryM5             5 3276.9 3309.0 -1633.4   3266.9 45.4845  1  1.539e-11 ***
operationM5         6 3265.0 3303.5 -1626.5   3253.0 13.9045  1  0.0001923 ***
stim_carry5         7 3266.5 3311.5 -1626.3   3252.5  0.4286  1  0.5126993    
operation_carry5    8 3268.5 3319.9 -1626.3   3252.5  0.0023  1  0.9620794    
stim_operation5     9 3270.5 3328.3 -1626.3   3252.5  0.0094  1  0.9228704    
trainingM5         10 3271.9 3336.2 -1626.0   3251.9  0.5838  1  0.4448132
```

I set up my contrasts like this:

```
ShamvsStim<- c(0, 1)
contrasts(dat$stim)<- ShamvsStim

AddvsSub<- c(0, 1)
contrasts(dat$operation)<- AddvsSub

CarryvsNC<- c(0, 1)
contrasts(dat$cond)<- CarryvsNC
```

And then analysed them:

```
> summary(trainingM5)
[...]

Fixed effects:
                       Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)             2.94373    0.23510  12.521  < 2e-16 ***
stim1                   0.09146    0.31465   0.291    0.771    
cond1                  -0.95974    0.23691  -4.051  5.1e-05 ***
operation1             -0.40098    0.24842  -1.614    0.107    
stim1:cond1            -0.04803    0.29358  -0.164    0.870    
cond1:operation1       -0.13183    0.32034  -0.412    0.681    
stim1:operation1       -0.21473    0.30969  -0.693    0.488    
stim1:cond1:operation1  0.30303    0.38609   0.785    0.433
```

I dont get why operation1 is not significant anymore when p was 0.0001923 ***?

Can anyone explain?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought perhaps I did something wrong with my contrasts. Are they non orthogonal? If yes, I figure that I have to correct for FDR. But this still does not explain my question, right?